# Subject verb agreement and usage of "where"

Tags: subject-verb-agreement

I'm having trouble deciding which one is correct here. I know that if it just was:

"In this modern era where everyone is busy", Would be correct subject-verb agreement. I'm not sure about the other two below:

"In this modern era, where everyone, adults and children, is busy.."

"In this modern era, where everyone, adults and children,  are busy.."

I also have a small question of the usage of "where" here, Should it be where or when?

Comment: An era definitely implies a when and not a where in this case. Also, why modern? Isn't "this era" enough? Modernity began a long time ago...:)

Comment: Your examples are not complete *sentences*, so they shouldn't end with a full stop. A valid sentence might be, for example, ***In this modern era everyone - adults and children - is busy.***

Comment: Sorry, i missed the three points. It wasn't a full stop. The end was supposed to be :"are busy...:" to imply that the phrase continued, but i only cared to know about the subject verb-agreement of that part.

Comment: You should use a full stop (**.**) if it's a complete sentence, or an ellipsis (**...**) if you're indicating that there is more to follow, but just two dots (..) is unclear and not part of standard English orthography.

Answer (score 1):

The subject of *be* in your sentences is "everyone", so the verb should be inflected for the third-person singular: "**everyone**, adults and children, **is busy**...."

"Where" vs. "When" is really a different question entirely but I would say that "where" is fine in this context. Judging by Lambie's comments, some speakers might disagree with me about this though.

Comment: You advise "In an era where" over "In an era when", in formal writing?

Comment: @Lambie: "I would say that "where" is fine in this context." I didn't advise using anything *over* anything else. As far as I can see, the original post doesn't specify whether the writing is in a formal context, or in a less formal context like a blog post. And I'm not sure that "where" is less formal.

Comment: *Over* is just another way to say *instead of*.  In my experience, sentences that look like that are formal. It's not just friends' chit-chatting.....

Comment: @Lambie: Your comment saying that I "advise 'In an era where' over 'In an era when'" seemed to me to imply that I said that it would be better to use "where" than to use "when". What I actually said was that it seems fine to me to use "where". More than one wording can be correct, so by saying that one wording is **fine**, I haven't said anything about which wording is **preferable** (because I'm honestly not sure what I think about that).

Comment: I see, I guess I misunderstood.

Answer (score 0):

I would reword the sentence as follows:

"In an era when everyone, adults and children, is busy..".

Yes, singular verb to match everyone.

I would not use modern, as "in this modern era" is opposed to what? The "modern era" began a long time ago.

Here is an overview of the term modern, including modern era: [modern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modern_history).

I think reading the whole entry clarifies why using modern era is difficult in your sentence.

Answer (score 0):

> In this modern era where everyone, adults and children, is busy.

*Everyone* is singular.  Why?  *Everyone* can be "expanded" like this:

> In this modern era where every adult and child is busy

Regarding the choice between *where* and *when*, the question *where* wants a *place* for answer.

How does that relate to time?

Points on lines are places.  A common model to talk about time is a "line"--a model so common you have the concept and word *timeline*.

Points on a line are places and therefore we can say "where does X appear on this line."

Therefore - *points of time can also utilize a logical "line" model and questions can use "where"*.

The question *when* tends to want things like *X o'clock*, *later*, *tomorrow*, *today*, something like a specific date as an answer, or a phrase beginning with *during*.